# How to handle seperator inset in ios 5,6,7 and 8

Tags: uitableview, ios7, ios5, ios6

From now i am using custom image as separator in new classes.
But there are number of places where i am using default UITableView separator.
On ios 8 i have used below code to handle successfully.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Remove seperator inset
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {//it handles only in ios 7
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

// Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}

// Explictly set your cell's layout margins
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
}
```

but i am getting compile time error (no selector found setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins) on iOS 6 and 7, and obviously will get this error on iOS 5.
i thought

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
```

will handle this scenario.but it fails

So how do i put a check so that the chuck of code setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins and setLayoutMargins skip in versions 5, 6 and 7.

THANKS